# WebSocket4Net - The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation

Tags: apache, cordova, visual-studio-2015, websocket4net

I've been trying to use Apache Cordova in Visual Studio 2015 CTP, but I'm getting error: "*WebSocket4Net, The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation.*". I've tried:

1. Reinstall Visual Studio 2015 (and deleted previous version - 2013). In the setup I've marked Cordova tools.
2. I found some suggestion to download *WebSocket4Net(0.9).Binaries.zip* from **CodePlex** and copy it to specified folder. However, the file *WebSocket4Net.dll* I've already there in the folder *c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\ToolWindows* and looks it doesn't matter.

Environment: Windows 7 Professional

Any idea what can be done yet to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing Visual Studio 2015 copy it to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\ToolWindows.
>   Microsoft Visual Studio **12.0**